# Set focus for paper-input via radio button

Tags: input, radio-button, focus, polymer, paper-elements

In Polymer (1.0), how can I set the focus of the iron-input when (as example) radiobutton 'radio1' is selected.

```
<div>
  <div>Title:</div> 
  <paper-radio-group>
    <paper-radio-button name="radio1">Radio1Label</paper-radio-button>
    <paper-radio-button name="radio2">Radio2Label</paper-radio-button>
  </paper-radio-group>
  <paper-input-container>
    <input is="iron-input">
  </paper-input-container>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to bind a click [event](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/events.html) to `radio1`:

```
<paper-radio-button name="radio1" on-click="_setInputFocus">Radio1Label</paper-radio-button>
```

Then define the function `_setInputFocus` so that it [selects the input](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/utility-functions.html#utility-functions) and sets the [focus](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_html_focus.asp) to it:

```
<script>
    Polymer({
        is: 'the-name-of-your-element',
        _setInputFocus: function () {
            this.$$("input").focus();
        }
    });
</script>
```

**EDIT:** Now we want the input disabled until the user selects the radio button. So we give the `iron-input` the `disabled` attribute:

```
<paper-input-container>
    <input is="iron-input" disabled>
</paper-input-container>
```

Then we change our JavaScript function so that we remove the `disabled` attribute and sets the input focus:

```
<script>
    Polymer({
        is: "focus-test",
         _setInputFocus: function () {
            var inputElement = this.$$("input"); // grab the element
            inputElement.toggleAttribute("disabled", false); // remove the disabled attribute
            inputElement.focus(); // set the focus to this input
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, did the trick very well :). Any change to disable the field before the radiobutton was selected? So that the user cannot select the field before the radiobutton is selected first.

Comment: I've edited my answer so that the input is disabled until the user clicks the radio button.

Comment: No problems. Should be easy for you to now add a click event to `radio2` that disables the input when clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the `<paper-input>` instead of the `<paper-input-container>` element and then use

```
setTimeout(function() {
        this.$.tabname.inputElement.focus()
    }.bind(this), 200);
```

in your function. (The set timeout is sometimes necessary because if another element had focus and is about to close (e.g. an iron-dropdown) then you would have to wait for this to finish before giving focus to the input)